# Cannot connect to Firebase's Firestore Database New Collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem where I can connect my firebase database collection "Agricultures" but I cannot connect with the "Admins" collection. Here are some of my codes in my firebase file.

```
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const AgriColRef = collection(db, "Agricultures");
export const AdminColRef = collection(db, "Admins");

export default AgriColRef;
```

However, it returned with the error

```
[Vue warn]: Property "fname" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.    
at <AddAdmin onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< null > >    
at <RouterView>    
at <App>
```

including for the other attributes.

Here is the code in the AddAdmin file

```
<script>
import { AdminColRef } from '../firebase';
import { addDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'

export default {
    dataAdmin(){
        return {
            fname:null,
            lnama:null,
            workerno:null,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        async createAdmin() {
            console.log("Create");
            const addedDoc = await addDoc(AdminColRef, this.$dataAdmin);
            console.log(addedDoc);
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Next is in the router

```
import AddAdmin from '../components/admin/AddAdmin.vue'
const routes = [{
        path: '/add-admin',
        name: 'addAdmin',
        component: AddAdmin
    }]
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    routes
})

export default router
```

And in the App file

```
<nav>
   <router-link to="/add-admin">Add Admin</router-link>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thanks.   What line in the code that you shard doesn't do what you expect it to do? I'd also recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following the guidance in there gives you the best chance that we can help efficiently.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have updated it sir. Does this good sir? Sorry I am still have a long way to learn. Thank you for teaching me.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. I don't really understand the code, but that might be my lack of experience with Vue and its router. I hope somebody else spots what might be going on.